# Godaddy: Login is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

good day!

I am making my simple website. It has a login page. Everything is working well in my localhost. I can login successfully.

So, now. I have uploaded my website to the Godaddy, together with the database.

Now, If I login with correct credentials, same as what I did in localhost. I am not able to login. It redirects me back to login page. There are no error thrown.

But, if I login with wrong credentials, it throws me an error "Incorrect Username or Password" -> this is what inside my login.php

Which means I have able to contact with database successfully right? What may have been the problem?

I am using XAMPP, 7.1.1, I think this is the latest because I have just downloaded this last week. I also notice that GoDaddy PHP Version is 5.6

I have configured the credentials for the server

```
dname = myDB;
lhost = localhost;
uname = username;
pword = password;
```

PS: this credentials are not my exact credentials.

I also tried

```
dname = myDB;
lhost = website ip address;
uname = username;
pword = password;
```

Still no luck =(

EDIT: Php script for login

```
<?php
require("../../includes/bootstrap.php");
require("../../templates/user/users/login.php");
session_save_path("../../cgi-bin/tmp");
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
try{
$ACCOUNT_SECURITY = new CORE_ACCOUNT_SECURITY();
$ACCOUNT_SECURITY->blocking();
if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['password']){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?";
  $SQL_CLASS = new SQL_SERVER_CONNECTION();
  $PDO_HANDLER = $SQL_CLASS->PDO_CONNECTION();

  $statement = $PDO_HANDLER->prepare($sql);

  $statement->execute(array($_POST['username']));
  if($statement->rowCount()>0){
    $userdata = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $userdata['password'])){
      $_SESSION['uid']=$userdata['id'];
      $_SESSION['unm']=$userdata['username'];
      $_SESSION['upriv']="user";
      $_SESSION['params']=[];
      header("location:user.php");
    }else{echo "Incorrect Username or password";sleep(3);exit;}   
  }else{echo "Incorrect Username or password";sleep(3);exit;}
}
}catch(Exception $e){
echo "Your Request is Temporarily Denied for Security Purpose";
}
?>
```

I have placed a error log, here is what is thrown

```
[24-Apr-2017 04:19:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method CORE_ACCOUNT_SECURITY::isloggedin() should not be called statically in /home/*****/public_html/user/users/user.php on line 6
```

Here is my user.php

```
<?php
require("../../includes/bootstrap.php");
session_save_path("../../cgi-bin/tmp");
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
if(!CORE_ACCOUNT_SECURITY::isloggedin()){
header("location:login.php");       
exit;
}else{      
if($_SESSION['upriv']=='user'){
  require("../../templates/user/users/user.php");
}else{header("location:../../");}                        
}
?>
```

Comment: Check your cpanel for the DB domain name. In my experience this can be different to the webhosting IP. can you get admin access through your cpanel?

Comment: Instead of echoing 'Request Denied...' in your catch. Try echoing $e->getMessage(); should give you the reason for failing

Comment: @JasonJoslin, good idea =) wait a sec

Comment: @JasonJoslin, I have place that, It didnt throw me an error. If place a wrong credentials it gives me "Incorrect Username or password"

Answer (score 0):

Your Database details aren't listed as PHP variables, so you will not be able to do `mysqli_connect($dbname,$lhost,$uname,$pword)`. It may not fix it, but no other details are provided, so it is hard to troubleshoot. Try providing your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

There might be few things you need to check :

1. Please check file permission , May be do not have right permission
2. You may check error logs to get what exactly happening. Normally, godaddy give you the error log [How to get Godaddy Error logs](https://my.godaddy.com/help/working-with-error-logs-1197)
3. Please check either your db configuration in correct setup.

It will be best if you could provide your relevant php code.

Comment: Can you try to add ob_start(); at the top of the script. Looks like you might have multiple header problem. You may enable error display and observer. It might will show you the error.

Comment: 1. Everything is checked. 2.Ill try this one 3. It is correct. As you can see, I can login using wrong credentials.

Comment: Try change this line CORE_ACCOUNT_SECURITY::isloggedin()   to (new CORE_ACCOUNT_SECURITY) -> isloggedin();      Or add static keyword on isloggedin() function

Comment: Where? inside the login.php or user.php?